# Is it a bug of design of OpenCV's function "pyrDown"

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I see the declaration of `pyrDown`:

```
CV_EXPORTS_W void pyrDown( InputArray src, OutputArray dst,
                           const Size& dstsize=Size(), int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT );
```

so I assume the 3rd parameter `dstsize` could be something like: `Size(src.cols/4, src.rows/4`. But as the **[docs](http://docs.opencv.org/master/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=pyrdown#void%20pyrDown(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20const%20Size&%20dstsize,%20int%20borderType))** says:

> in any case, the following conditions should be satisfied:
>
> [image]

so only the default size `Size((src.cols+1)/2, (src.rows+1)/2)` is legal. Then why the parameter `dstsize` being needed? It seems so useless...

Here I find a similar question post:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/25281/pyrup-only-for-doubling-size/

and @berak commented there:

> pyramids only work in powers of 2

while I think *pyramids only work in power ONE of 2*, is that true?

Comment: _"in power ONE of 2"_, what do you mean with that?

Comment: @Ela782 I mean, pyrDown can ONLY generate a dst image **half width/height** of the src, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't check it thoroughly, but it seems like it. It's called _octaves_. Your question however seems valid why there is a _dstsize_ parameter. Maybe it can be used together with the border type?

Answer (score 2):

In English: When the width/height of the src is odd such as `2*x+1` , then when use `pyrDown` the half will be `(x+0.5)`, the default method to deal with such a situation is ceil it, this is `Size((src.cols+1)/2, (src.rows+1)/2)`, but we can also floor it by set dstsize.

In Chinese: 
(当图片边长是奇数时，折半后有 0.5 的小数，默认是向上取整，可以设置dstsize来向下取整）。

> Here is an image with shape of `(183, 275, 3)`.

[image]

> Then let's test `pyrDown` in Python, there are four possible dstsizes:

```
>>> img = cv2.imread(fname)
>>> img.shape
(183, 275, 3)
>>> img1 = cv2.pyrDown(img)
>>> img1.shape  # the default size is `Size((src.cols+1)/2, (src.rows+1)/2)`
(92, 138, 3)
>>> img2 = cv2.pyrDown(img, dstsize=(137, 91))
>>> img2.shape
(91, 137, 3)
>>> img3 = cv2.pyrDown(img, dstsize=(137, 92))
>>> img3.shape
(92, 137, 3)
>>> img4 = cv2.pyrDown(img, dstsize=(138, 91))
>>> img4.shape
(91, 138, 3)
```

Note:

```
shape: (h,w,c)
Size:  (w,h)
```